# Bootstrap carousel: image sticks out of parent div

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have a problem setting up bootstrap carousel on my page. I want the the image sticks out of the parent div (so the image should not be attached at the top of the parent div instead on the bottom). How can I achieve such a behaviour? I already tried some positioning without any success (always destroys the default carousel behaviour). I created a small sketch how it should look like:

[image: sketch]

Here is my current code:

```
<div id="body">
    <section id="projects">
        <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <!-- Indicators -->
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            </ol>
            <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                <div class="item active">
                    <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="http://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/03/9b/2d/f2/new-york-city.jpg" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="http://www.newyork-reise.de/start/frei1.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Controls --> <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
 <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>

        </div>
</div>
</section>
</div>
```

I also created a jsFiddle for that: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cr4nud63/)

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand exactly wat you want sadly... because at the moment your bootstrap caroussel is not attached to the "top" of the parent, it's just that your body doesn't surround the whole caroussel, but the caroussel's height is 100%... could you be more precise in what you want please?

Comment: I added a drawing to my question.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand I added a black background. Do you want something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/cr4nud63/1/

Comment: No not really. I want that the image sticks out of the section. In my drawing the section would be the lightblue background of my jsfiddle. The image should stick out a little bit of the section.

Comment: Like this ? http://jsfiddle.net/cr4nud63/2/

Comment: Then again, you might want to set the min-height of the wrapper to be the tallest picture you want, else it'd be a little bit weird

Comment: Perfect thank you very much. That was exactly what I was looking for. That's true setting the min-height of the wrapper should be there.

Comment: Ill post it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to have a wrapper that will put your "body" div absolutely at the bottom of your carousel like in this fiddle :

```
       #body {
bottom: 0;
height:200px;
background-color: lightblue;
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
}
.wrapper{
   position: relative;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cr4nud63/2/